# Date difference between pairs of dates per ID

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have data with 2 columns, in the following format:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 27/7/2020 |
| 1 | 15/3/2021 |
| 2 | 18/1/2020 |
| 3 | 1/1/2020 |
| 3 | 3/8/2020 |
| 3 | 18/9/2021 |
| 2 | 23/8/2020 |
| 2 | 30/2/2021 |

Now I would like to create a calculation field in Tableau to find per ID the difference between the different dates. For any value e.g. days.

For example for ID 1 the difference of the two dates according to calendar is 208 days. Next the difference of the second to third date for the same ID is 231 days.

Comment: I think you will need to use the RANK() function to generate this new computed field.

Comment: Table calcs are the only types of calculations in Tableau that can take row order into account

Answer (score 1):

A table calc like the following should do if you get the partitioning, addressing and ordering right — such as setting “compute using” to Date.

```
If first() < 0 then min([Date]) - lookup(min([Date]), -1) end
```